# Spring MappedInterceptor mapping syntax

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to set up some mapped interceptors in Spring and I can't find any docs that describe what the mapping syntax should be.

Consider this:

```
private MappedInterceptor[] createMappedInterceptor()
{
    MappedInterceptor impersonationInterceptor = new MappedInterceptor(
            new String[] {"*.do"}, new MyFirstInterceptor()
    );

    return new MappedInterceptor[]{
            environmentInterceptor
    };
}
```

As you can see from the example above the intention is to map an instance of MyFirstInterceptor to all requests ending in "*.do". This isn't working though, my interceptor isn't being fired. That leads me to believe that my mapping syntax is incorrect.

The Spring documentation isn't a great deal of help: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/MappedInterceptor.html

Does anyone know what the mapping syntax should be?

Answer (score 2):

I've done some investigation and it turns out that `"*.do"` is the wrong syntax. What is actually required is `"/*.do"`.

The URL that I'm testing against looks something like this:

```
http://localhost:8086/ROOT/app/page.do
```

The class that does this matching is [AntPathMatcher](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)